# What's the difference between numpy.take and numpy.choose?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

It seems that `numpy.take(array, indices)` and `numpy.choose(indices, array)` return the same thing: a subset of `array` indexed by `indices`.

Are there only subtle differences between the two, or am I missing something more important? And is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`numpy.take(array, indices)` and `numpy.choose(indices, array)` behave similarly on 1-D arrays, but this is just coincidence. As pointed out by jonrsharpe, they behave differently on higher-dimensional arrays.

### numpy.take

`numpy.take(array, indices)` picks out elements from a flattened version of `array`. (The resulting elements are of course not necessarily from the same row.)

For example,

```
numpy.take([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [0, 3])
```

returns

```
array([1, 4])
```

### numpy.choose

`numpy.choose(indices, set_of_arrays)` plucks out element 0 from array `indices[0]`, element 1 from array `indices[1]`, element 2 from array `indices[2]`, and so on. (Here, `array` is actually a set of arrays.)

For example

```
numpy.choose([0, 1, 0, 0], [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

returns

```
array([1, 5, 3, 4])
```

because element 0 comes from array 0, element 1 comes from array 1, element 2 comes from array 0, and element 3 comes from array 0.

### More Information

These descriptions are simplified – full descriptions can be found here: [numpy.take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html), [numpy.choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html). For example, `numpy.take` and `numpy.choose` behave similarly when `indices` and `array` are 1-D because `numpy.choose` first broadcasts `array`.

Answer (score 10):

They are certainly not equivalent, as you can see by giving the same arguments (switched) to both methods:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                  [5, 6, 7, 8], 
                  [9, 10, 11, 12], 
                  [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> np.choose([0, 2, 1, 3], a)
array([ 1, 10,  7, 16]) # one from each row
>>> np.take(a, [0, 2, 1, 3])
array([1, 3, 2, 4]) # all from same row
```

I suggest you read the documentation on [`take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) and [`choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of `np.choose()` behavior in the documentation.

- [numpy.choose(a, choices, out=None, mode='raise')[source]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html#numpy.choose)

```
np.choose(a,c) == np.array([c[a[I]][I] for I in ndi.ndindex(a.shape)])
```

### index array and choices

```
import numpy as np

print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Index array 'a' and array of choice(s).")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
a = np.array([4, 3, 2, 1])
print("'a' is {} shape is {}\n".format(
    a, a.shape
))
    
c = np.arange(60).reshape((5, 3, 4))
_choice = c[0]
print("An example choice is \n{} \nshape is {}\n".format(
    _choice,
    _choice.shape
))
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index array 'a' and array of choice(s).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'a' is [4 3 2 1] shape is (4,)

An example choice is 
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]] 
shape is (3, 4)
```

### Broadcast

> Given an “index” array (a) of integers and a sequence of n arrays
> (choices), a and each choice array are first broadcast, as necessary,
> to arrays of a common shape; calling these Ba and Bchoices[i], i =
> 0,…,n-1 we have that, necessarily, `Ba.shape == Bchoices[i].shape` for
> each i.

`Ba.shape == Bchoices[i].shape`.

```
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("np.choose() broadcasts 'a' and 'choice' to match (here only on a)")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
a = np.vstack([
    np.array(a) for i in range(_choice.shape[0])
])
print("Broadcast shape of 'a' is {}\n 'a' is \n{}\n.".format(a.shape, a))
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
np.choose() broadcasts 'a' and 'choice' to match (here only on a)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Broadcast shape of 'a' is (3, 4)
 'a' is 
[[4 3 2 1]
 [4 3 2 1]
 [4 3 2 1]]
```

### Choose values from choices

`c[a[I]][I] for I in ndi.ndindex(a.shape)`

> suppose that i (in that range) is the value at the (j0, j1, …, jm)
> position in Ba - then the value at the same position in the new array
> is the value in Bchoices[i] at that same position;

```
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Simulate np.choose() behavior of choosing elements c[a[I]][I]]]:")
print("np.array([ c[a[I]][I] for I in np.lib.index_tricks.ndindex(a.shape) ])")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
result = np.array([]).astype(int)
for I in np.lib.index_tricks.ndindex(a.shape):
    print("Selecting the element {} at c[{},{}]".format(
        c[a[I]][I].astype(int), a[I], I
    ))
    result = np.concatenate([result, [c[a[I]][I].astype(int)]])
    print("chosen items: {}".format(result))
    
print("\nResult is \n{}\n".format(
    result.reshape(a.shape)
))
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Simulate np.choose() behavior of choosing elements c[a[I]][I]]]:
np.array([ c[a[I]][I] for I in np.lib.index_tricks.ndindex(a.shape) ])
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Selecting the element 48 at c[4,(0, 0)]
chosen items: [48]
Selecting the element 37 at c[3,(0, 1)]
chosen items: [48 37]
Selecting the element 26 at c[2,(0, 2)]
chosen items: [48 37 26]
Selecting the element 15 at c[1,(0, 3)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15]
Selecting the element 52 at c[4,(1, 0)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52]
Selecting the element 41 at c[3,(1, 1)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41]
Selecting the element 30 at c[2,(1, 2)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41 30]
Selecting the element 19 at c[1,(1, 3)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41 30 19]
Selecting the element 56 at c[4,(2, 0)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41 30 19 56]
Selecting the element 45 at c[3,(2, 1)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41 30 19 56 45]
Selecting the element 34 at c[2,(2, 2)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41 30 19 56 45 34]
Selecting the element 23 at c[1,(2, 3)]
chosen items: [48 37 26 15 52 41 30 19 56 45 34 23]

Result is 
[[48 37 26 15]
 [52 41 30 19]
 [56 45 34 23]]
```

### np.choose(a,c)

```
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Run np.choose(a, c):")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(np.choose(a, c))
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Run np.choose(a, c):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[48 37 26 15]
 [52 41 30 19]
 [56 45 34 23]]
```