# Accessing chunks at once in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Provided a numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

I wonder how access chosen size **chunks** with chosen separation, both concatenated and in slices:

E.g.: obtain chunks of size 3 separated by two values:

```
arr_chunk_3_sep_2 = np.array([0,1,2,5,6,7,10,11,12])
arr_chunk_3_sep_2_in_slices = np.array([[0,1,2],[5,6,7],[10,11,12])
```

Wha is the most efficient way to do it? If possible, I would like to avoid copying or creating new objects as much as possible. Maybe **Memoryviews** could be of help here?

Comment: For the first part, what's wrong with `arr[[1, 3, 7, 11]]`? For the second, what have you tried? [And why do you think it's possible to do in-place?]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426452/whats-the-difference-between-numpy-take-and-numpy-choose

Comment: However, this doesn't solve the issue with arbitrary size chunks. I don't see clearly how to slice pieces of an array wihtout providing one by one the indexes of each value.

Comment: I don't see how the second part is related to the first one. Why not make a separate question off the second one?

Comment: Solved! only the second part happens to be meaningful

Comment: That `arbitrary` in `arbitrary size chunks` looks dubious. Don't you mean `given` chunk size? `arbitrary size chunks` could mean that the chunks in the output could have variable number of elements, which doesn't seem like the case from the posted expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with `masking` -

```
def slice_grps(a, chunk, sep):
    N = chunk + sep
    return a[np.arange(len(a))%N < chunk]
```

Sample run -

```
In [223]: arr
Out[223]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [224]: slice_grps(arr, chunk=3, sep=2)
Out[224]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 12])
```

**Approach #2**

If the input array is such that the last chunk would have enough runway, we could , we could leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides), inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929672/) to select `m` elements off each block of `n` elements -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640641/ @Divakar
def skipped_view(a, m, n):
    s = a.strides[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    shp = ((a.size+n-1)//n,n)
    return strided(a,shape=shp,strides=(n*s,s), writeable=False)[:,:m]

out = skipped_view(arr,chunk,chunk+sep)
```

Note that the output would be a view into the input array and as such no extra memory overhead and virtually free!

Sample run to make things clear -

```
In [255]: arr
Out[255]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [256]: chunk = 3

In [257]: sep = 2

In [258]: skipped_view(arr,chunk,chunk+sep)
Out[258]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])

# Let's prove that the output is a view indeed
In [259]: np.shares_memory(arr, skipped_view(arr,chunk,chunk+sep))
Out[259]: True
```

Comment: Good! The use of Modulo means it can be speeded up in Cython using C-like division.

Comment: I still don´t see a clear solution for the sliced version though

Comment: I mean how to arrive to `np.array([[0,1,2],[5,6,7],[10,11,12])`

Comment: @ibarrond That would be `slice_grps(arr, chunk=3, sep=2).reshape(-1,chunk)`. I solved for the generic flattened case because there might be cases when the output size isn't a multiple of `chunk`.

Comment: I see! i was just missing the reshape. About the output size being a multiple of chunk, i would leave that to the actual implementation. If I am applying this to a vector of size 10.000, I can handpick the behaviour of the last chunk without severely impacting performance

Comment: @ibarrond Also, do check out `Approach #2`.

Comment: Damm, I can´t upvote or check the answer twice. I would if I could

Answer (score 2):

How about a reshape and slice?

```
In [444]: arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
In [445]: arr.reshape(-1,5)
...
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 13 into shape (5)
```

Ah a problem - your array isn't big enough for this reshape - so we have to pad it:

```
In [446]: np.concatenate((arr,np.zeros(2,int))).reshape(-1,5)
Out[446]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12,  0,  0]])
In [447]: np.concatenate((arr,np.zeros(2,int))).reshape(-1,5)[:,:-2]
Out[447]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

`as_strided` can get a way with this by including bytes outside the databuffer.  Usually that's seen as a bug, though here it can be an asset - provided you really do throw that garbage away.

Or throwing away the last incomplete line:

```
In [452]: arr[:-3].reshape(-1,5)[:,:3]
Out[452]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```